# FileSaver.js with Angular 7

Tags: excel, angular, download, angular7, filesaver.js

I have a use case where I need to download data as an excel file. I am using Angular 7 (UI) and Java Spring REST API service. The REST API will generate the Excel file and send it to Angular where I use FileSaver.js module to save the file to disk. I see the blob being created and the size printed on the console, but the file does not save to disk.

This used to work when I had Angular 4. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, if anybody can suggest an alternative node module to achieve the same result, I am all ears.

Below is the code snippet in Angular

```
this.myService.getDataAsXLSX(this.dataList).
    subscribe(byteArray => { 
            this.excelFileAsByteArray = byteArray; 
        }, error => console.log("There was an error."), 
        () => { 
            const blob = new Blob([this.excelFileAsByteArray.body], {type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; ; charset=UTF-8'}); 
            console.log('Blob size in filtered = ' + blob.size); 
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "MyData-" + this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy') + ".xlsx"); } );
```

Here is the code from the REST API

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ExcelWriter().createExcelWorkbook(dataList, fullName); 
    byte[] byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

responseHeaders.set("Content-Type","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; ; charset=UTF-8");

responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=MyData.xlsx"); responseHeaders.set("Expires", "0");

    return new ResponseEntity(byteArray, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Your `blob` `type` looks a bit weird, think you have an extra `application` and a semi-colon.

Comment: That was a typo and I fixed it. Still does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set responseType as 'blob' as 'json'. Content type as 'application/vnd.ms-excel'

```
public getDataAsXLSX(list: Array<any>) {
    return this.http.get(this.url, {
         headers: this.headers,
         responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
    });
}
```

Comment: This is what I have on the GET call.

  public getXLSX(): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>{
    return this.http.get(Endpoints.VULNERABILITY_REPORT_XLSX, {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'blob',
    });
  }